# Is there a better way to reconstruct Entity classes from the DBContext modified entries

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Currently I am using the Following code to recontruct an entity from the DBContext modified entries

Assuming that my entity class is

```
public partial class JournalEntryCode : IAuditColumns
{
    public JournalEntryCode()
    {
        this.JournalEntries = new HashSet<JournalEntry>();
    }

    public int journal_entry_code_pk { get; set; }
    public string journal_entry_code { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime tstamp { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<JournalEntry> JournalEntries { get; set; }
}
```

currently I go through the following routine to implement a solution to this problem (and it works) but I have to believe that there is a more elegant way to do this...

```
    private List<JournalEntryCode> GetListModifedEntities()
    {
        List<JournalEntryCode> listJournalEntryCodes = new List<JournalEntryCode>();
        var changeInfo = Context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                            .Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Modified)
                            .Select(t => new
                             {
                                Current = t.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.ToDictionary(pn => pn, pn => t.CurrentValues[pn]),
                             });
        foreach (var change in changeInfo)
        {
            JournalEntryCode jec = new JournalEntryCode();
            foreach (var pair in change.Current)
            {
                switch (pair.Key)
                {
                    case "journal_entry_code_pk":
                        jec.journal_entry_code_pk = (int)pair.Value;
                        break;
                    case "journal_entry_code":
                        jec.journal_entry_code = (string)pair.Value;
                        break;                       
                    case "tstamp":
                        jec.tstamp = (DateTime)pair.Value;
                        break;                        
                }
            }
            listJournalEntryCodes.Add(jec);
        }
        return listJournalEntryCodes;
    }
```

Comment: Try the [generic `Context.ChangeTracker.Entries<JournalEntryCode>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696335(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DbPropertyValues` has a method [`ToObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbpropertyvalues.toobject%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) that you can use to create a new, detached object from e.g. the current values of an entity:

```
return Context.ChangeTracker.Entries<JournalEntryCode>()
              .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified)
              .Select(e => e.CurrentValues.ToObject())
              .Cast<JournalEntryCode>()
              .ToList();
```